# How to run remote ssh session from Jenkins with sudo rights?

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, remote-access, sudo

Using 'Execute shell script on remote host using ssh' option and need sudo rights on remote server to change permissions and remove protected files.
How to run session with this rights?

Getting message

> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

when trying to run sudo command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote server accepts the direct login of the `root` user you can simply do:

```
ssh -l root yourserver command_to_execute
```

Similar syntax is:

```
ssh root@yourserver command_to_execute
```

Mind that allowing the login of the `root` user via ssh to a remote server  isn't always a good solution.
A better solution would be change the owner / permissions to allow a non-root user to modify the protected files.

Comment: This is a security risk. Should never allow root to ssh. Instead, regular user with sudo priviledges.

Comment: @Oliver, you're right. In the answer I added "Mind that allowing the login of the root user via ssh to a remote server isn't always a good solution."

Comment: I wanted to make a stronger statement for lesser experienced people who read the accepted answer, as "isn't always a good solution" means it is usually good but not always good. Whereas I'm saying, it is usually not good and may be justified in a few situations.

Answer (score 5):

To run `sudo` remotely you have 2 options

1. Allow the user to run `sudo` commands without a password.

Append `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` the `/etc/sudoers` file with `sudo visudo`. Alternatively you can modify this line to only allow certain `sudo` commands to be run without a password

2. Use the pseudo-tty to emulate tty remotely and enter your `sudo` password when requsted.

To do this run `ssh -t username@host command_to_execute`

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu22.04

```
sshCommand(remote: remoteConfig, command: 'echo 1 | sudo -S systemctl daemon-reload')
```

Use it like this

```
 stage("ssh upload") {
    steps {
      withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
              credentialsId: "${REMOTE_CRED}",
              keyFileVariable: "privateKeyFilePath"
      )]) {
        script {
            remoteConfig = [:]
            remoteConfig.name = "my-remote-server"
            remoteConfig.host = "${REMOTE_HOST}"
            remoteConfig.port = 22367
            remoteConfig.allowAnyHosts = true
            remoteConfig.user = "ubuntu"
            // SSH private key
            remoteConfig.identityFile = privateKeyFilePath
            sshPut(remote: remoteConfig, from: 'cyberVillageServer', into: '/home/ubuntu/myapp/')
            sshCommand(remote: remoteConfig, command: 'echo 1 | sudo -S systemctl daemon-reload')
        }
      }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).